# Как создать папку dist через команду build

Tags: node.js

Не могу разобраться, как сбилдить проект nodejs, чтобы при запуске команды npm run build появлялась папка dist, что нужно прописать в package.json в скрипте build?

Comment: «появлялась папка» — ну например `mkdir dist`. // «сбилдить проект» — вам как автору проекта лучше знать, как нужно билдить ваш собственный проект

Comment: Существуют разные сборщики js проектов. Для вебпака, например, нужно сконфигурировать его по документации и добавить в скрипты скажем ‘"build": "webpack"‘.